# NSJSON Loop Trouple

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, nslog, nsjsonserialization

I am getting my data but it seems like the data is posting in NSLog everytime it finds my "is reservable"=1;  I think this should only post once and when I display it in a tableview cell would it post more than once?
Here is my NSLog:

```
2012-08-31 11:35:39.682 GBSB[2168:15b03] These are the times avail: (
)
2012-08-31 11:35:39.683 GBSB[2168:15b03] These are the times avail: (
    "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)
2012-08-31 11:35:39.683 GBSB[2168:15b03] These are the times avail: (
    "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:15:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)
2012-08-31 11:35:39.683 GBSB[2168:15b03] These are the times avail: (
    "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:15:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)
2012-08-31 11:35:39.684 GBSB[2168:15b03] These are the times avail: (
    "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:15:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:45:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)
2012-08-31 11:35:39.684 GBSB[2168:15b03] These are the times avail: (
    "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:15:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:45:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)
2012-08-31 11:35:39.684 GBSB[2168:15b03] These are the times avail: (
    "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:15:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 08:45:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 09:15:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)
```

Here is my code I am using.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data

    NSError* error;

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


    NSDictionary* myslots =[json objectForKey:@"slots"];
    for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
    NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];
        NSArray *tests = [myslots objectForKey:slotKey];
        NSMutableArray *timesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *myDays in tests){

        if ([[myDays objectForKey:@"isReservable"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])
          [timesArray addObject:[myDays objectForKey:@"begin"]];

       NSLog(@"These are the times avail: %@", timesArray);

    }
    }
```

Comment: This is our fourth question today, all seemingly about the exact same problem. And its your eighth incomprehensible question about JSON.

Comment: I have been making progress on each question. The other questions were accepted already.

Comment: That's fine, but asking question after question about the same project implies that you are not doing enough to find the answers on your own.

Comment: Should I have just replace existing question each time I get a little further? Sorry about that.

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that either. Just try to work through the answer yourself as much as you can before posting.

Comment: It looks like you have the `NSLog` inside your loop. Wouldn't you expect it to be called repeatedly?

Comment: I have been but I am still learning. Thank you for all the advice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16109/discussion-between-woz-and-tidev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are forgetting your brackets for your `if` statement:

```
for (NSDictionary *myDays in tests){
    if ([[myDays objectForKey:@"isReservable"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
        [timesArray addObject:[myDays objectForKey:@"begin"]];
        NSLog(@"These are the times avail: %@", timesArray);
    }
}
```

Does that fix it? Test it out and let me know.

Comment: I had to move the NSLog out of first bracket. Another issue now but one solved. Thanks!